# Who are the 13 million migrants that the Victory Party wants to send back?

Tags: parties, immigration, turkey

https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65708268

> The Victory Party leader said this week Mr Kilicdaroglu had agreed to send back "13 million migrants" within a year "in line with international law".
>
> Turkey is hosting more refugees than any other country, but nowhere near that many.

I guess the Syrians are included. Who else does the Victory Party sees as deportable from Turkey? (Or is the
Victory Party just disputing the official figures from Syria that way?)

Comment: I wonder if recent pumpkin latte Russians are included in that number.

Comment: context to help parse previous comment [How Pumpkin Latte Became a Metaphor for New Russian Immigrants in Israel](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-01-10/ty-article-magazine/.premium/how-pumpkin-latte-became-a-metaphor-for-new-russian-immigrants-in-israel/00000185-96fb-d85f-a58d-fffbceff0000) and [Pumpkin latte scandal or social media controversy among Russian-language immigrants in Israel: Online talk in February](https://blogs.helsinki.fi/russianmedialab/2023/02/07/pumpkin-latte-scandal-or-social-media-controversy-among-russian-language-immigrants-in-israel-online-talk-in-february/)

Answer (score 2):

Numbers may very well be *greatly* exaggerated.  [From hrw.org Nov 2022](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/11/18/turkey-pushes-afghans-back-iran-border), aside Syrians, most seem to be Afghan:

> Turkey hosts the largest number of refugees of any country in the world, an estimated 3.9 million people, 3.6 million Syrians with temporary protection and 320,000 others, mostly Afghans.

Now, I am not going to vouch for HRW's exact numbers which may want to minimize the issue, but it's both hard to see them missing out by a factor of 4x and failing to identify the main ethnicities at hand.

[UN cites similar numbers](https://www.unhcr.org/tr/en/refugees-and-asylum-seekers-in-turkey):

> Türkiye currently hosts some 3.6 million registered Syrian refugees along with close to 320,000 persons of concern from other nationalities.

Afghans also regularly show up in accounts of refugees in Europe and Turkey seems a fairly natural point of passage, if they leave through Iran.

Comment: It is curious that playing the illegal inmigration card is allowed for US-backed opposition in Turkey (is he?) whereas it was highly verboten for US-backed opposition of Russia.

Comment: @alamar No idea what you are talking about as neither the US nor Russia figured in the Q or A.  Something to do with the wrong latte flavoring?